# How to implement a "method override" on a struct (pass a closure to a struct?)

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and still learning how to represent different designs patterns in the language, plus my recent background is all heavily OO design which is not helping think about the problem.

In the example below I want to eliminate the `sort_ascending` condition into something more elegant and ideally have it fully resolve at compile time.

```
struct MyList {
    ladder: Vec<i32>,
    sort_ascending: bool,
}

impl MyList {
    pub fn new(data: &[i32], sort_ascending: bool) -> MyList {
        return MyList {
            ladder: data.to_vec(),
            sort_ascending: sort_ascending,
        };
    }

    pub fn get_best(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
        if self.sort_ascending {
            return self.ladder.iter().reduce(|a, b| if a >= b { a } else { b });
        } else {
            return self.ladder.iter().reduce(|a, b| if a <= b { a } else { b });
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyList::new(&[10, 4, 30, 2, 5, 2], true);
    let r = x.get_best();
    println!("{:?}", r);

    let x = MyList::new(&[10, 4, 30, 2, 5, 2], false);
    let r = x.get_best();
    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

I think the solution lies in making the closure passed to `reduce()` configurable and have tried many variations along the following lines without success:

```
struct MyList<F>
    where F : Fn(i32,i32) -> i32
{
    ladder: Vec<i32>,
    sort_closure : F
}

impl<F> MyList<F> 
    where F : Fn(i32,i32) -> i32
{
    pub fn new(data: &[i32], sort_ascending: bool) -> MyList<F> {
        
        if sort_ascending { 
            return MyList {
                ladder: data.to_vec(),
                sort_closure : |a, b| if a >= b { a } else { b },
            };
        } else {
            return MyList {
                ladder: data.to_vec(),
                sort_closure : |a, b| if a <= b { a } else { b },
            };
        }
    }

    pub fn get_best(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
            return self.ladder.iter().reduce(self.sort_closure);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyList::new(&[10, 4, 30, 2, 5, 2], true);
    let r = x.get_best();
    println!("{:?}", r);

    let x = MyList::new(&[10, 4, 30, 2, 5, 2], false);
    let r = x.get_best();
    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

I would really appreciate any pointers on how to make the above code compile, or a pointer towards what would be the correct approach to take to implement this pattern.

Comment: Do you really need a closure (i.e. something able to capture its environment), or [would a simple function pointer suffice](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e13eb1bf5900be930808331fa7cdebb1)?

Comment: One simple modification of your first example could be to use a `const` generic, like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0282db76df970f3010e32d6b24ff410)—however `MyList`s with different sort directions would then be *different types* which might not be desirable.

Comment: @jmb I don't need a closure per se, I just need to be able to pass it in as a support function to something like an iterator

Comment: @eggyal thanks, that's useful. In your approach how would you avoid duplicating other methods on the struc which are common to both cases?

Comment: @IanAsh: You'd put them in a generic impl block, as I did with the `new` function.  Indeed, you could implement `get_best` that way too, switching on the constant `SORT_ASCENDING` within the function body (which would get optimised away during compilation/monomorphization), but I though it was clearer here to explicitly separate the impls even though there's a little bit of repetition.

Comment: [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5419c95cdfb8bfd48b85b31cb7bccf2f)'s a variation on @Jmb's approach, passing in `Iterator::max` or `Iterator::min` instead of a boolean.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, My Q was daft, problem of reading code on my phone! This is really helpful. Incidentally, using max/min functions directly isn't applicable in my case, as the actual use case doesn't have an ordinal in the vector.

Comment: jmb / eggyal: Thank you, both your comments were really helpful to my understanding. If you want to turn them into formal answers I'll up vote them.

Comment: Perhaps that’s an indication that you *should* implement `Ord` for the item type.  Even if not, you might still prefer to use `Iterator::max_by` and `Iterator::min_by` rather than `Iterator::reduce`, as the intent is a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward fix is to use a function pointer (`fn`) instead of trying to use a generic parameter on `MyList`.

The following solution is similar to what user Jmb suggested in the comment above, but simplified further by

- Avoiding lifetimes in the function pointer
- Using `std::cmp::{max, min}` instead of writing our own closures (though the code still works if you were to define the closures yourself, as before)

```rust
use std::cmp;

struct MyList {
    ladder: Vec<i32>,
    sort_closure: fn(i32, i32) -> i32,
}

impl MyList {
    pub fn new(data: &[i32], sort_ascending: bool) -> MyList {
        MyList {
            ladder: data.to_vec(),
            sort_closure: match sort_ascending {
                true => cmp::max,
                false => cmp::min,
            },
        }
    }

    pub fn get_best(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.ladder.iter().copied().reduce(self.sort_closure)
    }
}
```

### Why the original approach doesn't work

This is what the `MyList` definition looked like:

```rust
struct MyList<F>
    where F : Fn(i32,i32) -> i32
{
    ladder: Vec<i32>,
    sort_closure : F
}
```

The reason this doesn't work has to do with the type parameter `F` on `MyList`. Having the type paramter there means the caller (the code in `main()`) is free to instantiate `MyList<F>` with any `F` of their choosing that satisfies the `Fn(i32,i32) -> i32` constraint. However, inside the `MyList::new()` function, we are defining our own two closures, then trying to store one of them in `MyList`. This is the contradiction. The caller doesn't get to pick the type of the closure to be stored, except indirectly with the `sort_ascending` flag.